# How to get serial number of drive in storage pool

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, powershell, storage, storage-spaces

I have a storage pool in windows 8.1 and notice that whenever I boot the computer, it hangs for a long time in the detecting IDE drives during post. When it finally gets into windows, it shows one of the drives I have in a storage pool as disconnected. I am guessing that drive is failing. I have been searching how to get the serial number of the drive since most of the drives in my machine are the same size and I can't tell one from the other other than the serial number.

Is there a powershell command or some other command I can use to see the serial number of the drives in my storage pool? Most results from searching has pointed to windows server 2012 and the screenshots of the menus/windows those guides do not exist in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little playing around I found this got me the result I wanted.

```
$colItems = Get-PhysicalDisk 

foreach ($objItem in $colItems) {
    write-host "HealthStatus: " $objItem.HealthStatus
    write-host "SerialNumber: " $objItem.SerialNumber
    write-host
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the powershell cmdlet for Get-WmiObjet with the Win32_LogicalDiskClass object. It returns the serial number of the volume.   For example,

```
Write-Host "Drive information for $env:ComputerName"

Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk |
    Where-Object {$_.DriveType -ne 5} |
    Sort-Object -Property Name | 
    Select-Object Name, VolumeName, VolumeSerialNumber, FileSystem, Description, VolumeDirty, `
        @{"Label"="DiskSize(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) -as [float]}}, `
        @{"Label"="FreeSpace(GB)";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB) -as [float]}}, `
        @{"Label"="%Free";"Expression"={"{0:N}" -f ($_.FreeSpace/$_.Size*100) -as [float]}} |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

You can modify the above to get what you want.

Comment: I typed in `Get-WmiObject` into powershell and it prompted me to enter a class name. After entering `Win32_LogicalDisk` I see the three disks (I have more than that in terms of physical disks) and their sizes. No serial numbers.

Comment: @Justin Sorry, I typed my original answer using my phone.  It does not allow for formatting your answer.  Please see my updated answer.